# Passing a Cython extension type method to a pure C function

Tags: python, c, pass-by-reference, cython

I have a Cython extension type, let's call it `Foo`, and I'd like to be able to pass an 'instance' of it (isn't it like a struct?) in to a pure-C function so I can call a method of the extension type from C. I've tried piecing together how I might do this from various SO and mailing list posts but haven't been able to get it to work. My C skills are fairly rusty...

**I know the below is wrong for a number of reasons**, but hopefully it at least illustrates what I'd like to do...Thanks for your patience!

**test.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void cfunc(void* foo, double derp) {
    double r = foo.bar(derp);
    printf("%f", r);
}
```

**cy_test.pyx**:

```
import cython
cimport cython

cdef extern from "/tmp/test.c":
    void cfunc(void*, double)

cdef public class Foo[type FooType, object Foo]:
    cdef double spam

    def __init__(self, spam):
        self.spam = spam

    cdef public double bar(self, double q) nogil:
        q *= 15. + self.spam
        return q

cpdef call_func():
    foo = Foo(1.5)
    cfunc(&foo, 10.)

call_func()
```

Comment: It would really help to give names that reflect some realistic use case, rather than generic names like `Foo` and `spam`; that might make it clear why, for example, you're passing a `Foo` object to have its `bar` called by (presumably non-Python-centric, non-OO) C code rather than passing a bound method as a callable in the first palce.

Answer (score 2):

Python objects are of type `PyObject*`, which can be manipulated via the Python/C API.  You'll probably find [`PyObject_CallMethod()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod) and its relatives most useful here.

You may find it easier to write a C function in Cython that does what you want (i.e. a `cdef` function), and then call that from C code.  That way, Cython does all the annoying `PyObject*` fiddling (including reference counting) and you just get your desired result.